# Enable/Disable `Navigator` pane in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to enable/disable `Navigator pane` of highchart by some `Javascript/Jquery` code but not find any suitable code or clue to do that.

Please help me.

I have created `jsfiddle` for some sample to achieve that

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/f9V8G/13/)

-Neeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the click function to this:

```
$('#Navigator').click(function () {

    chart.update({
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });

});
```

The navigator enabled setting needs adding within the update.

Comment: Thanks, But after disabled, it would not enable again `http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/f9V8G/14/`

Comment: You're missing an 'r' in your ID. You've got `<button id="Navigato1">Navigator-Show</button>` and it needs to be `<button id="Navigator1">Navigator-Show</button>`. It is working though when the typo is corrected.